# PHP explode function End of Line detection

Tags: php

I'm using the explode function in tandem with the implode to take a CSV text and make it display clearly on screen, like so:

```
$CSV_STRING = 'Quarterly update,,
Question Topic,Question Title,Question Text
Question Topic,Question Title,Question Text';

----------------------

$array = explode(PHP_EOL, $CSV_STRING);

$arrayImploded = implode("<br>", $array);

$arrayExploded = explode(",", $arrayImploded);

$arrayFinal = implode("<br>", $arrayExploded);

echo $arrayFinal;
```

---

My issue here is that I'm trying to detect the new line with PHP_EOL and it doesn't seem to detect it. I've used `\n` and `\n\r` to similar results.

What should I use to correctly display my results like so:

---

```
Quarterly update


Question Topic
Question Title
Question Text 

Question Topic
Question Title
Question Text
```

---

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome.  Please see how to create an [mcve].  As-is, your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: Try with \r\n instead of \n\r

Comment: @fpierrat Still not working but thank you.

Comment: what does HTML source reveal? I wonder why you're imploding on the `<br>` tag though.

Comment: "\n" or "\r\n"... Double quotes, no single quotes

Answer (score 0):

Rather than exploding/imploding, you should be able to run it through [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) which will convert the new lines to `<br />` tags and then if you just use `str_replace()` to replace the commas with `<br />` tags as well, it should display as you want...

```
$CSV_STRING = 'Quarterly update,,
Question Topic,Question Title,Question Text
Question Topic,Question Title,Question Text';

$out = nl2br($CSV_STRING);
$out = str_replace("<br />", "<br /><br />", $out);
echo str_replace(",", "<br>", $out);
```

To create an extra break between the blocks, this just adds another `<br />` tag to each one just added.

Note that I've used `<br>` rather than `<br />` so you should see which part of the code is changing which part of the original string.  But use `<br />` for 'correctness'.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for this. Issue now is that there is not line break in between each block.

Comment: I've added another bit which should double up on the replaced tags.